# Asyncio unexpected output

Tags: python

I just started learning python asyncio, below is my simple code:

```py
import asyncio
import time

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def hello():
    print("Hello")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("World")

async def main():
    for _ in range(10):
        asyncio.ensure_future(hello())

start_time = time.time()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
duration = time.time() - start_time
print(duration)
```

But the result is like this:

```py
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
0.007950782775878906
```

Why is it not printing "World"?

Answer (score 1):

You need to await on the results of the calls to `hello` in order to ensure the entire body of the function `hello` is executed. The call `loop.run_until_complete(main())` runs the event loop until `main` finishes, however, your code does not require that the calls to `hello` finish before `main` can finish. You need to explicitly make termination of `main` depend on termination of all calls to `hello`.

You can achieve the desired behaviour using `asyncio.gather` like this:

```
import asyncio
import time

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def hello():
    print("Hello")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("World")

async def main():
    tasks = []
    for _ in range(10):
      tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(hello()))
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

start_time = time.time()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
duration = time.time() - start_time
print(duration)
```

which produces:

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
World
World
World
World
World
World
World
World
World
World
2.097428560256958
```